# Add 6 months to mysql field and subtract 1 week

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm developping a web application and it has files from users that last 6 months . I want the application to give a warning to the system Administrator 1 week before they expire.

I have the following MySQL table

```
##lar_pis##
#id_plano  nome_plano             data#
1         Plano Individual        2013-02-22
2         Plano Individual         2013-01-04
3         Plano Individual       2013-02-22
4         Plano Individual        2013-01-20
5         Plano Individual       2013-02-22
6         Plano Individual        2013-02-22
```

So far I only have

```
SELECT * 
FROM lar_pis
WHERE data =  DATE_ADD(data, INTERVAL 6 MONTHS)  ? AND SUBTRACT ONE WEEK ?
```

Comment: you can use event scheduler or cron jobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way,

```
SELECT * FROM lar_pis WHERE data = DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(data, INTERVAL 6 MONTHS), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't explained well myself .I want to get all dates that have 5 months and 3 weeks long.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM lar_pis
WHERE (data BETWEEN $date1 AND $date2)
```

Then define the $date1/2 variables with PHP date()?

Answer (score -1):

I made it using PHP like this :

```
$hojemenosseis = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-6 months"));
 <?php while($rowpis = mysql_fetch_assoc($querypis)){
 if($hojemenosseis == $rowpis["data"])
 { ... }
```